# Fragment Shader Error of writing to more than 1 ouput

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

The following is my code for a fragment shader to generate a texture on the floor and sphere and a fog effect above it.

I get an error which says "Fragment shader writes to more than 1 type of output gl_FragData, gl_FragColor or user bound frag data." when I try to compile it.

```
out vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoord;

uniform int fogType;
uniform int enableFloorTexture;
uniform int sphereTexture;
uniform int objectType;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler1D stexture;

void main() 
{ 
vec4 finColor = color;   
if (objectType == 1) 
{
    if(enableFloorTexture == 1) 
    {
        finColor = color * texture2D( texture, texCoord );
    }
} 
else if (objectType == 2) 
{
    if(sphereTexture != 0) 
    {
        finColor = color * texture1D( stexture, texCoord.x );
    }
}

float fogFactor = 0.0;
float fogDepth = (18.0 - 0.0);
float fogDensity = 0.09;
vec4 fogColor = vec4(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5);
float z = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;

if(fogType == 1) 
{
    fogFactor = (18.0 - z) / fogDepth;
} 
else if (fogType == 2) 
{
    fogFactor = exp( -fogDensity * z  );
}
else if (fogType == 3) 
{
    fogFactor = exp( -fogDensity * fogDensity * z * z );
}
fogFactor = clamp(fogFactor, 0.0, 1.0);

if(fogType == 0) 
{
    gl_FragColor = finColor; 
} 
else 
{
    gl_FragColor = mix(fogColor, finColor, fogFactor);
}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What confuses me in your program is that you are using `color` as an output but you are using it in your program. Is this just a slip of a pen?

If you want to use `#version 400`output format,the output should be like this:

```
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some outputs declared:

```
out vec4 color;
out vec2 texCoord;
```

Try making them inputs.

Comment: Tried doing that. The program keeps crashing. No change

Comment: Hmm.  I would comment out most code until it compiles & doesn't crash.  Then uncomment code until it breaks again.  Hopefully there will be a clue as you uncomment...